# audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]). Explain this code

Tags: javascript

I have created a drum kit from a lesson about js but I don't really understand what does it mean ans particularly the second line . This is the js code

```
window.addEventListener('keydown' , event => {
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
if(!audio) return;
audio.play();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line creates an event listener that listens for a key to be pressed.
On the second line it is selecting an `audio` element where the attribute `data-key` is equal to the key code of the keyboard event, and storing it in a variable. `document.querySelector` uses CSS selectors to select the first element it comes across with matching credentials. `event.keyCode` gets a Unicode value representing the key. These symbols `` create a template literal. This: ${event.keyCode} substitutes event.keyCode into the query selector. Like if I did:

```
console.log(`Visits: ${30 + 20}`);
```

I would expect: `"Visits: 50"`

On the third line, it checks if the audio element exists, and if it does not, it breaks out of the function with a `return` statement before the sound can play on the fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

It attaches an event to window object which triggers on a keydown on keyboard.

In second line audio object from window is selected by using querySelector to and passing selector "audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]".

"event.keyCode" contains the value of key that is pressed which helps to select the audio which should be played on that key.

In third line it checks if the audio element is present if it is not it returns out of function else the audio is played.